# Vue wait for API call before loading data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a this vue component where I'm using highcharts and I have an axios API call that populates the testresults array.I want the chartoptions variable to wait for the api call this is my code so far

```
<template>
  <div>
<highchart :options="chartOptions" />
<div>{{testresults}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testresults: [],
      loadAPI: false,
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Visual Test results'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['passed', 'failed', 'skipped']
        },


        series: [{
          name: 'Results',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{
            name: 'passed',
            y: this.testresults.pass,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          }]
        }]
      }

    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/backend/getresults`);


      this.testresults = res.data.data[0];
      console.log(testresults)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

I m getting an error that it cannot read properties of undefined pass

Comment: Could put `chartOptions` as a computed property. That way it will be updated when any dependent data is changed.

Comment: Or you could set `chartOptions` inside the `then` block after your axios request finishes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lissy93 I figured out that I could use `finally` after my api call where I would update chartOptions for anyone wondering this is what worked for me

```
<template>
  <div>
<highchart :options="chartOptions" />
<div>{{testresults}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios"

  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        testresults:[],
        loadAPI:false,
        chartOptions:{}

    }
  },
          async mounted() {
      try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/backend/getresults`);
      
      
      this.testresults=res.data.data[0];
      console.log(testresults)
      }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
      }finally{
                this.chartOptions={
            chart: {
                   plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
            },
              tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
            title: {
                text: 'Visual Test results'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['passed','failed','skipped']
            },
         
            
               series: [{
    name: 'Results',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{      name: 'passed',
      y: this.testresults.pass,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true}]
        }]
      }
      }
    },
    computed:{
      
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: It's a wrong way to do this. The first thing is that finally can be executed after an error, and data that you need may not be there. The second thing is that you're inconsistent about data, testresults was defined as an array but is used as an object.